# How to setup Vary: Origin in Cloudfare I want to return this param in the request header

Tags: cloud, cdn

I'm having this issue `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, so doing some research I've found that this is because Chrome is caching an specific request, so the response is comming from the Chrome cache (not from the API) and it does not contain the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. So the solution aparently for this is to include in the header response the param "Vary: Origin" but since I'm using Cloudfare as a CDN I'm having a hard time finding a way to include that parameter in the response header for this API. Has someone done this setup in the pass using Cloudfare?.

I've tried this setup on cloudfare but it didn't work: [image] so, maybe I'm missing something, and to be honest It's been really difficult to find any documentation on how to setup this Header `Vary: Origin` on cloudfare.